# How to filter data using search and hide uncompatible results in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a searchbox and a div list populated by database using ajax in my project. My first plan is to focus/highlight and scroll on the specific result. But i am having a hard time doing that. Now, I want to filter the result of my search and hide the other uncompatible results.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vEACM/1/

`enter code here`

Hope to help me in this problem. Thanks and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `:contains()` selector at this context to simplify your job,

```
$(function () {
    $('.search-field').on('keyup blur change', function () {
        $("li").removeClass("highlight");
        $('li:contains(' + this.value + ')').addClass('highlight');
    });
});
```

Side Note : `:contains()` selector is case sensitive one.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vEACM/7/)

For hiding unnecessary results use this, http://jsfiddle.net/vEACM/8/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('.search-field').on('keyup blur change', function() {
        var text_s = $(this).val();
        $("li").removeClass("highlight");
        if (text_s.length > 0){
            $("li").each(function(){
                var li_value = $(this).text();
                if (li_value.indexOf(text_s) >= 0){
                    $(this).addClass("highlight");
                     $(this).show();
                }
                else{
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/Cw4g2/